# Speeding up For loop for large dataframe

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, data.table

I have a very large dataframe and my goal is to list the cumulative USD by user ID.  The dataframe looks like this, but it is much larger:

```
dt<-sample(seq(as.Date("2013-01-01"),as.Date("2013-05-01"),by="days"),10)
s<-c(rep(5252525,5),rep(1313131,5))
usd<-round(rnorm(10,100),2)
money<-data.frame(dt,s,usd)
money<-money[order(money$dt),]
money$Cumulative<-NA
users<-unique(money$s)
```

I started with a for loop, but it was very slow:

```
for (i in 1:length(users)){
    temp=which(money$s==users[i])
    money$Cumulative[temp]=cumsum(money$usd[temp])
}
```

I read on StackOverflow that I could use data.table to improve overall speed, and this helped somewhat:

```
money<-data.table(money)
setkey(money,s)

for (i in 1:length(users)){
    temp=which(money$s==users[i])
    money$Cumulative[temp]=cumsum(money$usd[temp])
}
```

I'd like to make this calculation even faster.  What should I do next?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `money` is already ordered by the `dt` column, you can just use `ave`:

```
money$Cumulative <- ave(money$usd, money$s, FUN=cumsum)
```

Or you can use data.table:

```
moneyDT <- as.data.table(money[,1:3])
moneyDT[,cumulative := cumsum(usd), by=s]
```

Comment: The ave() function saved me lots of computer time.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for the `data.table` option.

Using Joshua's proposed methods and pointing out that using toy data can be misleading (i.e. methods similar perform similarly for minimal dataset `lil_money`, but not for more realistic dataset `money`):

### Results

```
Unit: microseconds
              expr     min      lq  median      uq       max neval
 useAve(lil_money) 694.269 730.491 741.358 756.753 13687.951  1000
  useBy(lil_money) 709.664 748.603 759.470 775.770  5341.338  1000

Unit: milliseconds
          expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
 useAve(money) 3940.8970 3966.0950 4002.4319 4090.3967 4145.2672    10
  useBy(money)  105.7129  106.5789  109.6566  117.2939  122.1414    10

Identical output: TRUE
```

### Code

```
require(microbenchmark)
require(data.table)

start <- as.Date("2001-01-01")
money <- CJ(s=1:1e4, dt=start + 0:1e3)[, usd := runif(.N)]

lil_money <- money[s < 10 & dt < start + 10]

useAve <- function(DT) { DT[, cum_ave := ave(usd, s, FUN=cumsum)] }
useBy <- function(DT) { DT[, cum_by := cumsum(usd), by=s] }

print(microbenchmark(useAve(lil_money), useBy(lil_money),  times=1000))
print(microbenchmark(useAve(money), useBy(money),  times=10))

cat("Identical output:", identical(money$cum_ave, money$cum_by))
```